# How to know scope of a variable in coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

In Coldfusion, I want to know the scope of a particular variable, how can i get that?

Actually in an existing cfm file one variable is used which is not declared in that page.But as it is not throwing any error thats why I am thinking this variable might be declared in some other scope.

So can I know in which scope it is declared?

Comment: If the page is an included file, the variable might be declared on the page that includes it.

Comment: @DanBracuk: yes same issue.Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried searching the code base for the variable name to find out where it is set?

Answer (score 5):

There's no way to check what scope it is in - you can only check all the scopes:

```
StructKeyExists(variables, "myVar");
StructKeyExists(session, "myVar");
StructKeyExists(form, "myVar");
StructKeyExists(request, "myVar");
StructKeyExists(url, "myVar");
```

etc

Precedence of scopes here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09af4-7fdf.html

More on the topic here [What is the scope evaluation order in ColdFusion when setting a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230873/what-is-the-scope-evaluation-order-in-coldfusion-when-setting-a-variable)

Comment: Here is a full list of all possible scopes: http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Variables_30.html

Comment: getScope("myVar") would be a useful addition to the language. It would speed up debugging at least. It's certainly a function I would use often.